# How can I directly access an instance of a django message via django template?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-messages

As a part of my error response I am trying to add "show" to a collapsable container using something like:
`class="{{request.session.registration}}"` 
but instead of session use django messages so the "show" does not persist.

Right now I'm using a pretty janky workaround where I loop through all messages:

```
<form action = "registration" method = "POST" id="registration" 
    class="collapse container 
    {% for message in messages %}
        {% if 'registration' in message.tags%} 
        {{message}}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %} 
">
```

for reference, the message is added in the views.py via:

```
messages.info(request, 'show', extra_tags='registration')
```

**How can I call this message explicitly?**

Comment: It could be possible by a custom template tag. I would personally rather push that into session scope and then remove it once consumed though.

Comment: Setting a context variable isnt an option?

Comment: @SachinKukreja it might be .. are you suggesting to keep it as a message and **also** pass it in as context (only calling it as context)?

Comment: If you require it in `messages`, keep it. If you pass a boolean variable indicating to `show` or `hide` in the context, it will be better.